# Populating a dictionary with multiple lines as one string

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, bioinformatics, biopython

I have a file with multiple lines in FASTA format, which I want to break up in pieces and populate a dictionary with these pieces.

```
>piece_1 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam a pellentesque mi. 
>piece_2 
Integer dignissim ultrices eros a consequat. Praesent vestibulum
>piece_3 
Morbi eget sollicitudin mauris. Nunc varius felis 
vitae dui congue hendrerit. Nam semper venenatis auctor.  
Suspendisse potenti. Suspendisse facilisis velit vel convallis 
fringilla. Duis condimentum auctor mauris eu lobortis.
```

I want to create, from the text above, a dictionary which contains all separate pieces of text with the keys being `>piece_1` etc.

So far I managed to populate a dictionary with all keys, but I can't tell how to extract the texts from the file.

```
f = open('Output.txt', 'r')
mydict = dict()

for index, line in enumerate(f):
    if line[:1]=='>':
        mydict[index] = line #instead, the key should be line with the value being the relative text.
        print(line, end='')
```

Comment: Is this FASTA format?

Comment: It is @Chris_Rands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one approach using a simple iteration.

**Ex:**

```
result = []
with open(filename) as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if line.startswith(">"):             #Check if line starts with '>'
            result.append([line, []])        #Create new list with format --> [key, [list of corresponding text]]
        else:
            result[-1][1].append(line)       #Append text to previously found key. 

mydict ={k: "".join(v) for k, v in result}   #Form required dictionary. 
print(mydict)
```

**Output:**

```
{'>piece_1 \n': 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\nconsectetur adipiscing elit. Nam a pellentesque mi. \n',
 '>piece_2 \n': 'Integer dignissim ultrices eros a consequat. Praesent vestibulum\n',
 '>piece_3 \n': 'Morbi eget sollicitudin mauris. Nunc varius felis \nvitae dui congue hendrerit. Nam semper venenatis auctor.  \nSuspendisse potenti. Suspendisse facilisis velit vel convallis \nfringilla. Duis condimentum auctor mauris eu lobortis. '}
```

Comment: note, this silently overwrites any duplicate keys, and error would be more helpful with real FASTA format data

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using [Biopython](https://biopython.org/), it will be more robust and concise than writing your own solution:

```
>>> from Bio import SeqIO
>>> d = SeqIO.to_dict(SeqIO.parse('input.fa', 'fasta'))
```

For your data:

```
>>> d['piece_1']
SeqRecord(seq=Seq('Loremipsumdolorsitametconsecteturadipiscingelit.Namape...mi.', SingleLetterAlphabet()), id='piece_1', name='piece_1', description='piece_1', dbxrefs=[])
>>> str(d['piece_1'].seq)
'Loremipsumdolorsitametconsecteturadipiscingelit.Namapellentesquemi.'
```

Comment: Thanks, I agree that is more tailored to my needs. However, since I am trying to learn Python I want to take the 'regular' route instead. This will likely come in handy later though, cheers.

Comment: Note spaces are removed from the output here, since they should not be in real FASTA sequencing datasets

Comment: That's perfectly fine. The original file contains DNA sequences, which I edited for common readability

Comment: If you want to understand how to write this in Python, the source code is quite readable https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/master/Bio/SeqIO/FastaIO.py#L24

Answer (score 1):

you could is a `collections.defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict
result = defaultdict(list)
index = None
for line in text:
    if line.startswith(">"):
        index = line[1:]
    else:
        result[index].append(line)
```

> ```
> {
>     "piece_1 ": [
>         "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
>         "consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam a pellentesque mi. ",
>     ],
>     "piece_2 ": [
>         "Integer dignissim ultrices eros a consequat. Praesent vestibulum"
>     ],
>     "piece_3 ": [
>         "Morbi eget sollicitudin mauris. Nunc varius felis ",
>         "vitae dui congue hendrerit. Nam semper venenatis auctor.  ",
>         "Suspendisse potenti. Suspendisse facilisis velit vel convallis ",
>         "fringilla. Duis condimentum auctor mauris eu lobortis.",
>     ],
> }
> ```

Comment: I am a complete novice at python. Could you expand on how this works?

Comment: If you're a novice in Python, I suggest you real [A Whirlwind Tour of Python](https://jakevdp.github.io/WhirlwindTourOfPython/index.html). About the `defaultdict` and what it does specifically, you can check the excellent [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html)

Comment: Neat! My master's will be heavily intertwined with Python, so I'm trying to prepare myself. That literature will come in handy

Answer (score 0):

Here's another compact possibility using list and dict comprehensions:

```
with open('Output.txt', 'r') as f:
    s = f.read()
result = {k.strip(): v for k, v in [part.split('\n', maxsplit=1)
                                    for part in s.split('>')[1:]] }
```

In the inner list comprehension: The 0th list element that `s.split('>')` returns is an empty string, so we ignore it. `maxsplit=1` in the subsequent split at `\n` prevents splitting the text in more than 2 pieces.

Comment: Very clean, and it confirms my suspicion it was doable in fewer lines. This does however put line breaks `\n` right in the values